# How to add all values in one column in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I got a query code which I get all data from database which is an int in my database then I get all data using while then declare a total variable which will display the total value. For ex. I got 5 and 2 in my database so the output should be 7 but then the output is 52 which is adding as text instead of int.

```
 <?php
$st='SELECT rating FROM rating;';
$t=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($t,$st);
mysqli_stmt_execute($t);
$res=mysqli_stmt_get_result($t);
while($rop=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $total=0;
 $total+=$rop['rating'];
 echo $total;
}
```

Comment: `$total = 0;` needs to be _before_ the loop. You're resetting it on each iteration at the moment. Then `echo $total` should be after the loop.

Comment: Thanks that works like magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use MySQL's [SUM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function:

```
SELECT sum(rating) as total from rating
```

This query will directly give you the sum of all the column values.

So, the final code should be:

```
$st='SELECT sum(rating) as total from rating';
$t=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($t,$st);
mysqli_stmt_execute($t);
$res=mysqli_stmt_get_result($t);
$total=0;
while($rop=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
 $total = $rop['total'];
}
 echo $total;
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. Didn't know about SELECT sum thanks again

Comment: You can directly use MySQL functions and remove the need of looping.

Comment: yeah it looks much cleaner using it thnks alot

Answer (score 0):

Change your query from

```
$st='SELECT rating FROM rating;';
```

to

```
$st='SELECT sum(rating) as total_sum FROM rating;';
```

Also change

```
while($rop=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $total=0;
 $total+=$rop['rating'];
 echo $total;
}
```

to

```
$total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)['total_sum'];
echo $total;
```

- Also, it is not a good practice to have column names same as table names.

Comment: I got an error array to string conversion so should I use while loop then echo it out?

Comment: @JenelHapitana I made a fix. Refresh your page to see the updated code.